# Trend button on a report not visible (Einstein Analytics)

Tags: reporting, einstein-analytics

I have a EA enabled developer org. I'm looking at some videos and the latest [Spring'20 documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_trend_create.htm&type=5) wondering why I can't see the green Trend button on reports in my org.
Judging by the [comments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uucgajb-cDg) there are more people confused by the feature.
I can't spot a setting that would make the button appear. Could someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a permission set with the permission "[Trend Report Data in Analytics](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_setup_user_permissions.htm)" and enable "historical trending" in your Org. With this you should be able to see the "Trend" button in reports.

Inase you are unable to see the 'Trend Report Data in Analytics' in the "System Permissions" of the permission set, you need to check the Einstein Analytics licenses provisioned in your org.

Incase you are still unable to view this permission despite having needed licenses, please log a case with salesforce support asking to 'Enable Trending Report data' permission on your Org.